# Display section and subsection headers on same page with large table or figure

Tags: tables, sectioning, landscape, sections-paragraphs

I am struggling to put the table (or figure) on the same page where I have specified my section (subsection). Does anyone of you know how to do this? Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{a4paper,left=25.4mm,right=25.4mm,top=25.4mm,bottom=25.4mm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}\epstopdfsetup{update}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=0pt}\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=small, skip=0pt, labelformat=empty}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
%-------graphs begin at top of page--------------------------------%
\makeatletter
\setlength\@fptop{0pt} 
%%\setlength\@fpsep{8pt plus 1fil}
\setlength\@fpsep{2pt}
\setlength\@fpbot{0pt}
\makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Table: Total WTP and Absolute WTP Contributions in total WTP}
%%-----begin tables---------------------------%%
\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.0ex}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{onehalfspace}
%\begin{footnotesize}
\caption{\textbf{Total WTP and Absolute WTP Contributions in WTP} \label{table1}}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccc}
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{11}{c}{}\\[-2.8ex]
&\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{WTP and Absolute Contributions to WTP (\euro/mnth) in 2007}}
&\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{WTP and Absolute Contributions to WTP (\euro/mnth) in 2011}} \\
\multicolumn{11}{c}{}\\[-2.8ex]                 
\cmidrule(r){2-6} \cmidrule(r){7-11} 
\multicolumn{11}{c}{}\\[-2.8ex]
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$WTP$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{${WTP^{a}}$}
                           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{${WTP^{h}}$} 
                           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{${WTP^{n}}$}
                           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{${WTP^{u}}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$WTP$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{${WTP^{a}}$}
                           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{${WTP^{h}}$} 
                           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{${WTP^{n}}$}
                           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{${WTP^{u}}$} \\                   
\multicolumn{11}{c}{}\\[-2.8ex]
\hline
Austria     &      524.60&       64.21&      351.90&       93.56&       14.92&      564.09&       59.08&      388.97&       93.95&       22.10\\
Belgium     &      568.72&       76.23&      324.96&      136.36&       31.18&      583.87&      101.82&      365.13&       85.74&       31.17\\
Bulgaria    &      170.71&       34.77&       75.01&       53.51&        7.41&      273.08&       65.19&      131.10&       50.87&       25.92\\
Cyprus      &      487.98&      112.41&      205.27&      153.86&       16.44&      567.77&      126.43&      254.29&      152.58&       34.46\\
Czech Republic&      358.85&       44.43&      231.90&       77.53&        4.98&      401.78&       51.25&      273.73&       66.68&       10.11\\
Germany     &      539.88&       52.30&      387.09&       76.31&       24.18&      637.33&       67.61&      449.12&       88.55&       32.06\\
Denmark     &      441.69&       90.85&      292.38&       50.77&        7.68&      493.83&       66.35&      368.21&       33.11&       26.16\\
Estonia     &      301.66&       81.67&      160.87&       54.61&        4.50&      370.63&       80.62&      238.73&       36.56&       14.72\\
Greece      &      391.24&       73.38&      126.39&      166.19&       25.27&      341.10&       72.43&      140.36&       90.39&       37.93\\
Spain       &      403.96&       46.62&      220.96&      111.58&       24.80&      446.12&       46.56&      259.03&       58.98&       81.54\\
Finland     &      449.89&       73.10&      321.46&       49.85&        5.48&      531.48&       81.05&      403.96&       30.51&       15.95\\
France      &      533.72&       88.15&      287.13&      134.61&       23.82&      585.92&      101.17&      366.29&       77.29&       41.17\\
Hungary     &      291.90&       53.67&      152.57&       76.35&        9.32&      351.13&       56.47&      232.61&       45.15&       16.90\\
Italy       &      690.68&       99.57&      346.04&      231.61&       13.45&      591.50&       74.25&      375.90&      119.01&       22.34\\
Lithuania   &      280.98&       69.57&      138.70&       66.51&        6.19&      297.55&       49.85&      188.49&       36.05&       23.17\\
Luxembourg  &      972.66&      148.27&      539.91&      260.70&       23.78&      932.12&      139.73&      673.81&       84.53&       34.05\\
Latvia      &      298.61&       84.04&      147.19&       61.32&        6.06&      328.21&       88.26&      196.47&       24.64&       18.83\\
Netherlands &      493.10&       74.09&      332.48&       75.73&       10.80&      595.87&       88.74&      442.59&       45.62&       18.92\\
Poland      &      316.78&       58.43&      147.72&       87.46&       23.17&      375.51&       63.00&      232.94&       53.32&       26.26\\
Portugal    &      387.26&       52.06&      208.62&      103.69&       22.88&      371.92&       65.31&      236.98&       30.62&       39.01\\
Romania     &      131.56&       33.36&       67.32&       29.35&        1.53&      191.48&       38.24&      119.72&       29.74&        3.78\\
Sweden      &      402.96&       54.78&      276.07&       55.00&       17.11&      503.85&       76.78&      344.87&       50.95&       31.25\\
Slovenia    &      544.01&       71.11&      365.14&       87.06&       20.70&      492.97&       55.61&      343.64&       46.81&       46.91\\
Slovakia    &      292.05&       44.29&      178.43&       64.83&        4.51&      375.85&       46.93&      266.47&       44.51&       17.95\\
United Kingdom&      638.47&      122.23&      366.44&      126.98&       22.81&      566.39&      105.83&      350.07&       71.19&       39.31\\
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{11}{p{29.0cm}}{Notes: Numbers denote mean values of (total) WTP and absolute contributions of non-income dimensions $d$, to total WTP ($WTP^{d}$) where $d\in (a, h, n, u)$. The results are weighted using the weights that do sum up to 1.\singlespacing} \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{onehalfspace}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
%%-----end tables------------------------------%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To place the section header, the subsection header, and the landscape-mode table all on one page, I suggest you do the following:

- Since the table shouldn't float (in the LaTeX sense of the word), don't use a `table` environment.
- Instead, place the tabular material, along with the caption (generated by `\captionof{table}{...}` instead of `\caption{...}`), in a `minipage` environment. Set the width of the `minipage` to something like 20cm -- wide enough so that all 11 columns of table fit without having to resort to tricks such as font size reductions, yet narrow enough so that the `minipage` will fit on the page along with the section and subsection headers.
- Using a `\rotatebox` instruction, rotate the `minipage` 90 degrees counterclockwise to place it in landscape mode.
- For the tabular material, use a `tabularx` environment. Set the width of the `tabularx` environment to `\linewidth` -- which will be 20cm since that's the width of the surrounding `minipage`.
- Align the numbers in columns 2 to 11 on their decimal markers using `S` column types (provided by the `siunitx` package), and use centered versions of the `X` column type for the header cells.
- Don't overuse **bold** -- clarity is achieved much more effectively via good layout than by **shouting in bold letters**.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{float,color}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx}
\sisetup{parse-numbers=false} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=0pt,font=bf}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=small, skip=0pt, labelformat=empty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

% --- floats on a floats-only page begin at top of page ---%
\makeatletter
\setlength\@fptop{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Table: Total WTP and Absolute WTP Contributions in total WTP}

\vspace*{1cm} % vertical offset

\noindent
\rotatebox{90}{%  % rotate the minipage 90 degrees counter-clockwise
\begin{minipage}{20cm}

\captionof{table}{Total WTP and Absolute WTP Contributions in WTP} \label{table1}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out widths of columns

\bigskip  % whitespace between caption and tabular material

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l *{10}{S[table-format=3.2]} }
\toprule
&\multicolumn{5}{>{\hsize=5\hsize}C}{WTP and Absolute Contributions to WTP (\euro/mnth) in 2007}
&\multicolumn{5}{>{\hsize=5\hsize}C}{WTP and Absolute Contributions to WTP (\euro/mnth) in 2011} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(l){7-11}
& \mc{$WTP$} & \mc{$WTP^{a}$} & \mc{$WTP^{h}$} & \mc{$WTP^{n}$} & \mc{$WTP^{u}$}
& \mc{$WTP$} & \mc{$WTP^{a}$} & \mc{$WTP^{h}$} & \mc{$WTP^{n}$} & \mc{$WTP^{u}$} \\
\midrule
Austria     &      524.60&       64.21&      351.90&       93.56&       14.92&      564.09&       59.08&      388.97&       93.95&       22.10\\
Belgium     &      568.72&       76.23&      324.96&      136.36&       31.18&      583.87&      101.82&      365.13&       85.74&       31.17\\
Bulgaria    &      170.71&       34.77&       75.01&       53.51&        7.41&      273.08&       65.19&      131.10&       50.87&       25.92\\
Cyprus      &      487.98&      112.41&      205.27&      153.86&       16.44&      567.77&      126.43&      254.29&      152.58&       34.46\\
Czech Republic&    358.85&       44.43&      231.90&       77.53&        4.98&      401.78&       51.25&      273.73&       66.68&       10.11\\
Germany     &      539.88&       52.30&      387.09&       76.31&       24.18&      637.33&       67.61&      449.12&       88.55&       32.06\\
Denmark     &      441.69&       90.85&      292.38&       50.77&        7.68&      493.83&       66.35&      368.21&       33.11&       26.16\\
Estonia     &      301.66&       81.67&      160.87&       54.61&        4.50&      370.63&       80.62&      238.73&       36.56&       14.72\\
Greece      &      391.24&       73.38&      126.39&      166.19&       25.27&      341.10&       72.43&      140.36&       90.39&       37.93\\
Spain       &      403.96&       46.62&      220.96&      111.58&       24.80&      446.12&       46.56&      259.03&       58.98&       81.54\\
Finland     &      449.89&       73.10&      321.46&       49.85&        5.48&      531.48&       81.05&      403.96&       30.51&       15.95\\
France      &      533.72&       88.15&      287.13&      134.61&       23.82&      585.92&      101.17&      366.29&       77.29&       41.17\\
Hungary     &      291.90&       53.67&      152.57&       76.35&        9.32&      351.13&       56.47&      232.61&       45.15&       16.90\\
Italy       &      690.68&       99.57&      346.04&      231.61&       13.45&      591.50&       74.25&      375.90&      119.01&       22.34\\
Lithuania   &      280.98&       69.57&      138.70&       66.51&        6.19&      297.55&       49.85&      188.49&       36.05&       23.17\\
Luxembourg  &      972.66&      148.27&      539.91&      260.70&       23.78&      932.12&      139.73&      673.81&       84.53&       34.05\\
Latvia      &      298.61&       84.04&      147.19&       61.32&        6.06&      328.21&       88.26&      196.47&       24.64&       18.83\\
Netherlands &      493.10&       74.09&      332.48&       75.73&       10.80&      595.87&       88.74&      442.59&       45.62&       18.92\\
Poland      &      316.78&       58.43&      147.72&       87.46&       23.17&      375.51&       63.00&      232.94&       53.32&       26.26\\
Portugal    &      387.26&       52.06&      208.62&      103.69&       22.88&      371.92&       65.31&      236.98&       30.62&       39.01\\
Romania     &      131.56&       33.36&       67.32&       29.35&        1.53&      191.48&       38.24&      119.72&       29.74&        3.78\\
Sweden      &      402.96&       54.78&      276.07&       55.00&       17.11&      503.85&       76.78&      344.87&       50.95&       31.25\\
Slovenia    &      544.01&       71.11&      365.14&       87.06&       20.70&      492.97&       55.61&      343.64&       46.81&       46.91\\
Slovakia    &      292.05&       44.29&      178.43&       64.83&        4.51&      375.85&       46.93&      266.47&       44.51&       17.95\\
United Kingdom&    638.47&      122.23&      366.44&      126.98&       22.81&      566.39&      105.83&      350.07&       71.19&       39.31\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{11}{p{\linewidth}}{\footnotesize Notes: Numbers denote mean values of (total) $WTP$ and absolute contributions of non-income dimensions $d$, to total $WTP$ ($WTP^{d}$) where $d\in (a, h, n, u)$. The results are weighted using the weights that do sum up to 1.} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. That's exactly what I wanted to achive.