# Large table in appendix

Tags: tables, landscape

I will present several tables in my appendix and want them in landscape view. Something like this,
[image]

Now my table is not even close to looking anything like that.

```
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Death rate in Sweden by age and year}

\subsection{Male}
\small
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}  
\rotatebox{90}{
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllllllllllllllll}
        & 1989 & 1990 & 1991 & 1992 & 1993 & 1994 & 1995 & 1996 & 1997 & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 & 2001 & 2002 & 2003 & 2004 & 2005 & 2006 & 2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 \\
        \hline
64 år   & 711  & 765  & 719  & 698  & 608  & 619  & 595  & 609  & 522  & 582  & 531  & 560  & 539  & 531  & 533  & 579  & 514  & 576  & 665  & 707  & 670  & 731  & 637  & 606  & 590  & 518  \\
65 år   & 843  & 804  & 774  & 778  & 721  & 698  & 620  & 653  & 673  & 626  & 557  & 553  & 551  & 544  & 620  & 600  & 617  & 644  & 669  & 686  & 734  & 739  & 743  & 669  & 652  & 616  \\
66 år   & 899  & 894  & 872  & 861  & 788  & 727  & 782  & 709  & 696  & 669  & 591  & 596  & 612  & 632  & 637  & 611  & 699  & 678  & 596  & 657  & 709  & 765  & 796  & 805  & 749  & 696  \\
67 år   & 1032 & 927  & 989  & 891  & 898  & 774  & 783  & 822  & 726  & 757  & 707  & 633  & 627  & 626  & 628  & 652  & 636  & 629  & 690  & 627  & 660  & 767  & 797  & 793  & 807  & 824  \\
68 år   & 1141 & 1119 & 1023 & 1026 & 980  & 909  & 896  & 846  & 809  & 775  & 801  & 724  & 724  & 687  & 710  & 682  & 703  & 663  & 697  & 741  & 651  & 697  & 844  & 803  & 878  & 866  \\
69 år   & 1324 & 1182 & 1197 & 1057 & 1048 & 986  & 968  & 921  & 868  & 861  & 829  & 827  & 766  & 790  & 705  & 739  & 721  & 708  & 715  & 780  & 763  & 755  & 830  & 856  & 914  & 954  \\
70 år   & 1122 & 1383 & 1311 & 1289 & 1144 & 1114 & 1043 & 1000 & 958  & 923  & 902  & 893  & 825  & 823  & 810  & 744  & 762  & 786  & 758  & 766  & 749  & 829  & 781  & 866  & 911  & 976  \\
71 år   & 1254 & 1271 & 1398 & 1349 & 1299 & 1155 & 1155 & 1170 & 1128 & 1040 & 1056 & 932  & 928  & 879  & 960  & 884  & 775  & 814  & 773  & 798  & 808  & 838  & 835  & 761  & 927  & 983  \\
72 år   & 1369 & 1368 & 1274 & 1495 & 1506 & 1347 & 1183 & 1158 & 1175 & 1139 & 1104 & 1086 & 988  & 1014 & 941  & 935  & 866  & 838  & 828  & 854  & 826  & 863  & 864  & 891  & 843  & 924  \\
73 år   & 1434 & 1423 & 1439 & 1386 & 1563 & 1500 & 1445 & 1318 & 1277 & 1232 & 1177 & 1116 & 1043 & 1080 & 1058 & 994  & 1010 & 906  & 884  & 861  & 913  & 877  & 923  & 993  & 943  & 869  \\
74 år   & 1583 & 1544 & 1505 & 1485 & 1397 & 1577 & 1723 & 1467 & 1399 & 1348 & 1287 & 1235 & 1182 & 1138 & 1121 & 1033 & 1088 & 1023 & 904  & 994  & 956  & 944  & 937  & 1032 & 1033 & 1064 \\
75 år   & 1622 & 1706 & 1621 & 1459 & 1534 & 1453 & 1660 & 1690 & 1587 & 1439 & 1475 & 1340 & 1272 & 1265 & 1197 & 1087 & 1137 & 1081 & 1062 & 1020 & 987  & 1033 & 985  & 1026 & 1071 & 1085 \\
76 år   & 1714 & 1752 & 1681 & 1569 & 1597 & 1548 & 1481 & 1694 & 1773 & 1705 & 1448 & 1453 & 1415 & 1302 & 1303 & 1224 & 1218 & 1189 & 1112 & 1051 & 1095 & 1014 & 1101 & 1086 & 1119 & 1116 \\
77 år   & 1862 & 1858 & 1874 & 1782 & 1795 & 1677 & 1678 & 1596 & 1776 & 1796 & 1700 & 1582 & 1510 & 1527 & 1445 & 1319 & 1284 & 1258 & 1219 & 1205 & 1171 & 1174 & 1129 & 1146 & 1126 & 1182 \\
78 år   & 1801 & 1888 & 1860 & 1822 & 1867 & 1714 & 1709 & 1593 & 1570 & 1870 & 1871 & 1687 & 1576 & 1600 & 1497 & 1373 & 1370 & 1334 & 1365 & 1307 & 1279 & 1325 & 1227 & 1196 & 1110 & 1197 \\
79 år   & 1874 & 1975 & 1854 & 1914 & 1856 & 1680 & 1796 & 1706 & 1665 & 1595 & 1919 & 1906 & 1788 & 1681 & 1621 & 1504 & 1566 & 1435 & 1345 & 1335 & 1295 & 1349 & 1319 & 1246 & 1219 & 1196 \\
80 år   & 1786 & 1906 & 1862 & 1882 & 1994 & 1860 & 1755 & 1763 & 1791 & 1652 & 1653 & 1879 & 1934 & 1846 & 1698 & 1630 & 1643 & 1580 & 1529 & 1468 & 1495 & 1452 & 1366 & 1400 & 1320 & 1288 \\
81 år   & 1819 & 1983 & 1968 & 1872 & 1933 & 1837 & 1821 & 1860 & 1815 & 1775 & 1816 & 1624 & 1975 & 1944 & 1990 & 1745 & 1741 & 1698 & 1603 & 1647 & 1503 & 1484 & 1365 & 1538 & 1405 & 1350 \\
82 år   & 1686 & 1810 & 1898 & 1940 & 1890 & 1775 & 1919 & 1821 & 1706 & 1761 & 1803 & 1763 & 1586 & 2045 & 1987 & 1777 & 1777 & 1698 & 1700 & 1639 & 1540 & 1560 & 1512 & 1544 & 1485 & 1486 \\
83 år   & 1671 & 1699 & 1792 & 1841 & 1845 & 1753 & 1814 & 1873 & 1795 & 1789 & 1793 & 1757 & 1753 & 1658 & 2068 & 1922 & 1900 & 1766 & 1758 & 1724 & 1653 & 1660 & 1662 & 1587 & 1515 & 1566 \\
84 år   & 1560 & 1632 & 1671 & 1681 & 1791 & 1728 & 1834 & 1804 & 1783 & 1845 & 1709 & 1729 & 1697 & 1715 & 1606 & 1959 & 2003 & 1917 & 1809 & 1761 & 1707 & 1648 & 1665 & 1661 & 1659 & 1540 \\
85 år   & 1395 & 1449 & 1543 & 1601 & 1659 & 1594 & 1718 & 1745 & 1713 & 1794 & 1719 & 1703 & 1697 & 1719 & 1710 & 1606 & 1963 & 1942 & 1816 & 1775 & 1808 & 1715 & 1712 & 1672 & 1598 & 1647 \\
86 år   & 1280 & 1424 & 1333 & 1404 & 1556 & 1460 & 1665 & 1635 & 1588 & 1641 & 1709 & 1695 & 1578 & 1605 & 1656 & 1574 & 1586 & 1902 & 1919 & 1828 & 1714 & 1748 & 1697 & 1741 & 1601 & 1605 \\
87 år   & 1141 & 1171 & 1210 & 1266 & 1368 & 1260 & 1375 & 1494 & 1440 & 1486 & 1510 & 1579 & 1496 & 1623 & 1538 & 1491 & 1571 & 1489 & 1761 & 1885 & 1784 & 1696 & 1705 & 1717 & 1619 & 1597 \\
88 år   & 961  & 1127 & 1083 & 1133 & 1205 & 1124 & 1240 & 1259 & 1347 & 1405 & 1409 & 1388 & 1426 & 1439 & 1424 & 1454 & 1449 & 1460 & 1411 & 1671 & 1761 & 1688 & 1559 & 1677 & 1544 & 1481 \\
89 år   & 849  & 955  & 954  & 907  & 1049 & 972  & 1038 & 1114 & 1138 & 1158 & 1279 & 1203 & 1249 & 1344 & 1314 & 1255 & 1274 & 1338 & 1288 & 1377 & 1529 & 1586 & 1544 & 1556 & 1619 & 1535 \\
90 år   & 683  & 741  & 815  & 879  & 864  & 759  & 888  & 904  & 985  & 1039 & 1054 & 1058 & 1129 & 1135 & 1097 & 1102 & 1182 & 1136 & 1201 & 1176 & 1201 & 1456 & 1459 & 1537 & 1329 & 1418 \\
91 år   & 622  & 593  & 657  & 657  & 721  & 720  & 730  & 836  & 805  & 860  & 890  & 881  & 982  & 956  & 982  & 952  & 956  & 987  & 994  & 999  & 1052 & 1084 & 1305 & 1345 & 1351 & 1194 \\
92 år   & 473  & 473  & 509  & 531  & 557  & 560  & 606  & 623  & 636  & 690  & 729  & 767  & 778  & 812  & 759  & 830  & 847  & 884  & 878  & 871  & 892  & 894  & 955  & 1121 & 1169 & 1086 \\
93 år   & 350  & 357  & 406  & 387  & 461  & 430  & 474  & 493  & 505  & 529  & 547  & 573  & 615  & 700  & 635  & 670  & 735  & 684  & 740  & 736  & 735  & 747  & 758  & 800  & 981  & 946  \\
94 år   & 270  & 285  & 313  & 299  & 326  & 307  & 349  & 353  & 380  & 368  & 424  & 437  & 434  & 454  & 478  & 452  & 558  & 524  & 604  & 585  & 600  & 577  & 618  & 619  & 666  & 727  \\
95 år   & 184  & 199  & 234  & 253  & 235  & 234  & 268  & 257  & 275  & 284  & 291  & 330  & 336  & 363  & 360  & 377  & 404  & 358  & 419  & 431  & 464  & 414  & 449  & 519  & 480  & 512  \\
96 år   & 126  & 147  & 169  & 153  & 199  & 173  & 159  & 198  & 198  & 197  & 224  & 241  & 245  & 262  & 269  & 236  & 262  & 310  & 308  & 297  & 316  & 334  & 317  & 348  & 356  & 351  \\
97 år   & 107  & 120  & 104  & 118  & 125  & 136  & 124  & 132  & 156  & 127  & 144  & 140  & 159  & 166  & 166  & 176  & 206  & 191  & 202  & 221  & 221  & 243  & 252  & 254  & 250  & 268  \\
98 år   & 68   & 76   & 64   & 72   & 68   & 78   & 73   & 77   & 72   & 88   & 89   & 110  & 111  & 96   & 106  & 126  & 113  & 135  & 153  & 137  & 169  & 151  & 162  & 168  & 171  & 164  \\
99 år   & 46   & 33   & 51   & 50   & 58   & 45   & 46   & 47   & 60   & 57   & 60   & 63   & 71   & 76   & 59   & 62   & 55   & 81   & 82   & 95   & 104  & 108  & 102  & 132  & 116  & 105  \\
100+ år & 63   & 56   & 72   & 63   & 69   & 64   & 72   & 88   & 78   & 74   & 83   & 80   & 100  & 95   & 94   & 97   & 93   & 108  & 128  & 130  & 146  & 165  & 128  & 166  & 156  & 190 
\end{tabular} }
\end{table} 

\end{appendices}
```

Any kind soul that could help me transform my table to look as good as the picture? Many karma points will be rewarded. Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[8 pt, a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[tmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
```

Comment: How big is the page (A4? US Letter?), and how wide are the margin? Is is imperative to have chapter and subsection headers *and* a very large table all on one page, or can be table maybe be placed on a page of its own?

Comment: I have amended the packages I use in the question. My paper is a4.

Comment: Thanks for posting an update. Incidentally, there is no `8pt` option for the `report` document class; hence `8 pt` will simply be ignored, meaning that the document's main font size is `10pt`.

Comment: Note that the table in the screenshot you've posted (obtained from [this site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270163/5001), right?) and your own table aren't really comparable: Yours has 27 columns, whereas the one in the screenshot only has 11 (admittedly somewhat wider) columns. Do reconsider how important it is to you that the chapter header, the subsection header, *and* the tabular material all fit on one and the same page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Given that your table is very large -- 38 rows (incl. the header row) and 27 columns -- don't even think about cramming a chapter header and a subsection header onto the page with the table. Instead, consider making the table caption more informative.
- Simplify the first column by removing all `år` strings from the data cells and by putting this bit of information in the header of the first column.
- Use a `sidewaystable` environment, a `tabular*` environment (with width set to `\textwidth`) instead of a `tabular` environment, and let LaTeX figure out the amount of intercolumn whitespace that will make the table fit inside the text block.
- Use left-alignment for the first column, and right-alignment for the 26 data columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page margins
\usepackage{rotating,caption,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\small
% Let LaTeX figure out amount of intercolumn whitespace
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 

\caption{Death rate in Sweden, by age and calendar year. (1) Males}
\label{my-label} 

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{26}{r} }
\AA r & 1989 & 1990 & 1991 & 1992 & 1993 & 1994 & 1995 & 1996 & 1997 & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 & 2001 & 2002 & 2003 & 2004 & 2005 & 2006 & 2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 \\
\midrule
64 & 711 & 765 & 719 & 698 & 608 & 619 & 595 & 609 & 522 & 582 & 531 & 560 & 539 & 531 & 533 & 579 & 514 & 576 & 665 & 707 & 670 & 731 & 637 & 606 & 590 & 518 \\
65 & 843 & 804 & 774 & 778 & 721 & 698 & 620 & 653 & 673 & 626 & 557 & 553 & 551 & 544 & 620 & 600 & 617 & 644 & 669 & 686 & 734 & 739 & 743 & 669 & 652 & 616 \\
66 & 899 & 894 & 872 & 861 & 788 & 727 & 782 & 709 & 696 & 669 & 591 & 596 & 612 & 632 & 637 & 611 & 699 & 678 & 596 & 657 & 709 & 765 & 796 & 805 & 749 & 696 \\
67 & 1032 & 927 & 989 & 891 & 898 & 774 & 783 & 822 & 726 & 757 & 707 & 633 & 627 & 626 & 628 & 652 & 636 & 629 & 690 & 627 & 660 & 767 & 797 & 793 & 807 & 824 \\
68 & 1141 & 1119 & 1023 & 1026 & 980 & 909 & 896 & 846 & 809 & 775 & 801 & 724 & 724 & 687 & 710 & 682 & 703 & 663 & 697 & 741 & 651 & 697 & 844 & 803 & 878 & 866 \\
69 & 1324 & 1182 & 1197 & 1057 & 1048 & 986 & 968 & 921 & 868 & 861 & 829 & 827 & 766 & 790 & 705 & 739 & 721 & 708 & 715 & 780 & 763 & 755 & 830 & 856 & 914 & 954 \\
70 & 1122 & 1383 & 1311 & 1289 & 1144 & 1114 & 1043 & 1000 & 958 & 923 & 902 & 893 & 825 & 823 & 810 & 744 & 762 & 786 & 758 & 766 & 749 & 829 & 781 & 866 & 911 & 976 \\
71 & 1254 & 1271 & 1398 & 1349 & 1299 & 1155 & 1155 & 1170 & 1128 & 1040 & 1056 & 932 & 928 & 879 & 960 & 884 & 775 & 814 & 773 & 798 & 808 & 838 & 835 & 761 & 927 & 983 \\
72 & 1369 & 1368 & 1274 & 1495 & 1506 & 1347 & 1183 & 1158 & 1175 & 1139 & 1104 & 1086 & 988 & 1014 & 941 & 935 & 866 & 838 & 828 & 854 & 826 & 863 & 864 & 891 & 843 & 924 \\
73 & 1434 & 1423 & 1439 & 1386 & 1563 & 1500 & 1445 & 1318 & 1277 & 1232 & 1177 & 1116 & 1043 & 1080 & 1058 & 994 & 1010 & 906 & 884 & 861 & 913 & 877 & 923 & 993 & 943 & 869 \\
74 & 1583 & 1544 & 1505 & 1485 & 1397 & 1577 & 1723 & 1467 & 1399 & 1348 & 1287 & 1235 & 1182 & 1138 & 1121 & 1033 & 1088 & 1023 & 904 & 994 & 956 & 944 & 937 & 1032 & 1033 & 1064 \\
75 & 1622 & 1706 & 1621 & 1459 & 1534 & 1453 & 1660 & 1690 & 1587 & 1439 & 1475 & 1340 & 1272 & 1265 & 1197 & 1087 & 1137 & 1081 & 1062 & 1020 & 987 & 1033 & 985 & 1026 & 1071 & 1085 \\
76 & 1714 & 1752 & 1681 & 1569 & 1597 & 1548 & 1481 & 1694 & 1773 & 1705 & 1448 & 1453 & 1415 & 1302 & 1303 & 1224 & 1218 & 1189 & 1112 & 1051 & 1095 & 1014 & 1101 & 1086 & 1119 & 1116 \\
77 & 1862 & 1858 & 1874 & 1782 & 1795 & 1677 & 1678 & 1596 & 1776 & 1796 & 1700 & 1582 & 1510 & 1527 & 1445 & 1319 & 1284 & 1258 & 1219 & 1205 & 1171 & 1174 & 1129 & 1146 & 1126 & 1182 \\
78 & 1801 & 1888 & 1860 & 1822 & 1867 & 1714 & 1709 & 1593 & 1570 & 1870 & 1871 & 1687 & 1576 & 1600 & 1497 & 1373 & 1370 & 1334 & 1365 & 1307 & 1279 & 1325 & 1227 & 1196 & 1110 & 1197 \\
79 & 1874 & 1975 & 1854 & 1914 & 1856 & 1680 & 1796 & 1706 & 1665 & 1595 & 1919 & 1906 & 1788 & 1681 & 1621 & 1504 & 1566 & 1435 & 1345 & 1335 & 1295 & 1349 & 1319 & 1246 & 1219 & 1196 \\
80 & 1786 & 1906 & 1862 & 1882 & 1994 & 1860 & 1755 & 1763 & 1791 & 1652 & 1653 & 1879 & 1934 & 1846 & 1698 & 1630 & 1643 & 1580 & 1529 & 1468 & 1495 & 1452 & 1366 & 1400 & 1320 & 1288 \\
81 & 1819 & 1983 & 1968 & 1872 & 1933 & 1837 & 1821 & 1860 & 1815 & 1775 & 1816 & 1624 & 1975 & 1944 & 1990 & 1745 & 1741 & 1698 & 1603 & 1647 & 1503 & 1484 & 1365 & 1538 & 1405 & 1350 \\
82 & 1686 & 1810 & 1898 & 1940 & 1890 & 1775 & 1919 & 1821 & 1706 & 1761 & 1803 & 1763 & 1586 & 2045 & 1987 & 1777 & 1777 & 1698 & 1700 & 1639 & 1540 & 1560 & 1512 & 1544 & 1485 & 1486 \\
83 & 1671 & 1699 & 1792 & 1841 & 1845 & 1753 & 1814 & 1873 & 1795 & 1789 & 1793 & 1757 & 1753 & 1658 & 2068 & 1922 & 1900 & 1766 & 1758 & 1724 & 1653 & 1660 & 1662 & 1587 & 1515 & 1566 \\
84 & 1560 & 1632 & 1671 & 1681 & 1791 & 1728 & 1834 & 1804 & 1783 & 1845 & 1709 & 1729 & 1697 & 1715 & 1606 & 1959 & 2003 & 1917 & 1809 & 1761 & 1707 & 1648 & 1665 & 1661 & 1659 & 1540 \\
85 & 1395 & 1449 & 1543 & 1601 & 1659 & 1594 & 1718 & 1745 & 1713 & 1794 & 1719 & 1703 & 1697 & 1719 & 1710 & 1606 & 1963 & 1942 & 1816 & 1775 & 1808 & 1715 & 1712 & 1672 & 1598 & 1647 \\
86 & 1280 & 1424 & 1333 & 1404 & 1556 & 1460 & 1665 & 1635 & 1588 & 1641 & 1709 & 1695 & 1578 & 1605 & 1656 & 1574 & 1586 & 1902 & 1919 & 1828 & 1714 & 1748 & 1697 & 1741 & 1601 & 1605 \\
87 & 1141 & 1171 & 1210 & 1266 & 1368 & 1260 & 1375 & 1494 & 1440 & 1486 & 1510 & 1579 & 1496 & 1623 & 1538 & 1491 & 1571 & 1489 & 1761 & 1885 & 1784 & 1696 & 1705 & 1717 & 1619 & 1597 \\
88 & 961 & 1127 & 1083 & 1133 & 1205 & 1124 & 1240 & 1259 & 1347 & 1405 & 1409 & 1388 & 1426 & 1439 & 1424 & 1454 & 1449 & 1460 & 1411 & 1671 & 1761 & 1688 & 1559 & 1677 & 1544 & 1481 \\
89 & 849 & 955 & 954 & 907 & 1049 & 972 & 1038 & 1114 & 1138 & 1158 & 1279 & 1203 & 1249 & 1344 & 1314 & 1255 & 1274 & 1338 & 1288 & 1377 & 1529 & 1586 & 1544 & 1556 & 1619 & 1535 \\
90 & 683 & 741 & 815 & 879 & 864 & 759 & 888 & 904 & 985 & 1039 & 1054 & 1058 & 1129 & 1135 & 1097 & 1102 & 1182 & 1136 & 1201 & 1176 & 1201 & 1456 & 1459 & 1537 & 1329 & 1418 \\
91 & 622 & 593 & 657 & 657 & 721 & 720 & 730 & 836 & 805 & 860 & 890 & 881 & 982 & 956 & 982 & 952 & 956 & 987 & 994 & 999 & 1052 & 1084 & 1305 & 1345 & 1351 & 1194 \\
92 & 473 & 473 & 509 & 531 & 557 & 560 & 606 & 623 & 636 & 690 & 729 & 767 & 778 & 812 & 759 & 830 & 847 & 884 & 878 & 871 & 892 & 894 & 955 & 1121 & 1169 & 1086 \\
93 & 350 & 357 & 406 & 387 & 461 & 430 & 474 & 493 & 505 & 529 & 547 & 573 & 615 & 700 & 635 & 670 & 735 & 684 & 740 & 736 & 735 & 747 & 758 & 800 & 981 & 946 \\
94 & 270 & 285 & 313 & 299 & 326 & 307 & 349 & 353 & 380 & 368 & 424 & 437 & 434 & 454 & 478 & 452 & 558 & 524 & 604 & 585 & 600 & 577 & 618 & 619 & 666 & 727 \\
95 & 184 & 199 & 234 & 253 & 235 & 234 & 268 & 257 & 275 & 284 & 291 & 330 & 336 & 363 & 360 & 377 & 404 & 358 & 419 & 431 & 464 & 414 & 449 & 519 & 480 & 512 \\
96 & 126 & 147 & 169 & 153 & 199 & 173 & 159 & 198 & 198 & 197 & 224 & 241 & 245 & 262 & 269 & 236 & 262 & 310 & 308 & 297 & 316 & 334 & 317 & 348 & 356 & 351 \\
97 & 107 & 120 & 104 & 118 & 125 & 136 & 124 & 132 & 156 & 127 & 144 & 140 & 159 & 166 & 166 & 176 & 206 & 191 & 202 & 221 & 221 & 243 & 252 & 254 & 250 & 268 \\
98 & 68 & 76 & 64 & 72 & 68 & 78 & 73 & 77 & 72 & 88 & 89 & 110 & 111 & 96 & 106 & 126 & 113 & 135 & 153 & 137 & 169 & 151 & 162 & 168 & 171 & 164 \\
99 & 46 & 33 & 51 & 50 & 58 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 60 & 57 & 60 & 63 & 71 & 76 & 59 & 62 & 55 & 81 & 82 & 95 & 104 & 108 & 102 & 132 & 116 & 105 \\
100$+$ & 63 & 56 & 72 & 63 & 69 & 64 & 72 & 88 & 78 & 74 & 83 & 80 & 100 & 95 & 94 & 97 & 93 & 108 & 128 & 130 & 146 & 165 & 128 & 166 & 156 & 190 \\
\end{tabular*} 
\end{sidewaystable} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico. You are so right about not having a header in the same page. I remove this and see what my mentor at uni thinks about it. The table looks great and is exactly how I want it to look like. x1000 karma points to you!

Comment: @Orongo -- Earlier today, the fourth upvote on this answer raised my rep total on this site above the 250,000 points threshold -- as well as awarded me the bronze "landscape" answer badge. Exactly 1066 badges now -- the Hastings Number! :-) Those "x1000 karma points" wishes you made really came true. Many thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest I can bring to the original image in question.  The chapter heading and the table are in the same page.

---

**The Code**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=20.0mm,right=15.0mm,top=10.0mm,bottom=10.0mm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0.0mm}{-10.0mm}{0.0mm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0.0mm}{0.0mm}{0.0mm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\appendix

\chapter{Death rate in Sweden by age and year}

\section{Male}

\begin{table}[!bp]
  \centering

  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.85\textheight}
      \def\arraystretch{1.2}
      \small\centering
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.0mm}
      \scriptsize
      \centering
      \caption{My caption}
      \label{my-label}  
      \begin{tabular}{l*{26}{r}}
        & 1989 & 1990 & 1991 & 1992 & 1993 & 1994 & 1995 & 1996 & 1997 & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 & 2001 & 2002 & 2003 & 2004 & 2005 & 2006 & 2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 \\
        \midrule
        64 år   & 711  & 765  & 719  & 698  & 608  & 619  & 595  & 609  & 522  & 582  & 531  & 560  & 539  & 531  & 533  & 579  & 514  & 576  & 665  & 707  & 670  & 731  & 637  & 606  & 590  & 518  \\
        65 år   & 843  & 804  & 774  & 778  & 721  & 698  & 620  & 653  & 673  & 626  & 557  & 553  & 551  & 544  & 620  & 600  & 617  & 644  & 669  & 686  & 734  & 739  & 743  & 669  & 652  & 616  \\
        66 år   & 899  & 894  & 872  & 861  & 788  & 727  & 782  & 709  & 696  & 669  & 591  & 596  & 612  & 632  & 637  & 611  & 699  & 678  & 596  & 657  & 709  & 765  & 796  & 805  & 749  & 696  \\
        67 år   & 1032 & 927  & 989  & 891  & 898  & 774  & 783  & 822  & 726  & 757  & 707  & 633  & 627  & 626  & 628  & 652  & 636  & 629  & 690  & 627  & 660  & 767  & 797  & 793  & 807  & 824  \\
        68 år   & 1141 & 1119 & 1023 & 1026 & 980  & 909  & 896  & 846  & 809  & 775  & 801  & 724  & 724  & 687  & 710  & 682  & 703  & 663  & 697  & 741  & 651  & 697  & 844  & 803  & 878  & 866  \\
        69 år   & 1324 & 1182 & 1197 & 1057 & 1048 & 986  & 968  & 921  & 868  & 861  & 829  & 827  & 766  & 790  & 705  & 739  & 721  & 708  & 715  & 780  & 763  & 755  & 830  & 856  & 914  & 954  \\
        70 år   & 1122 & 1383 & 1311 & 1289 & 1144 & 1114 & 1043 & 1000 & 958  & 923  & 902  & 893  & 825  & 823  & 810  & 744  & 762  & 786  & 758  & 766  & 749  & 829  & 781  & 866  & 911  & 976  \\
        71 år   & 1254 & 1271 & 1398 & 1349 & 1299 & 1155 & 1155 & 1170 & 1128 & 1040 & 1056 & 932  & 928  & 879  & 960  & 884  & 775  & 814  & 773  & 798  & 808  & 838  & 835  & 761  & 927  & 983  \\
        72 år   & 1369 & 1368 & 1274 & 1495 & 1506 & 1347 & 1183 & 1158 & 1175 & 1139 & 1104 & 1086 & 988  & 1014 & 941  & 935  & 866  & 838  & 828  & 854  & 826  & 863  & 864  & 891  & 843  & 924  \\
        73 år   & 1434 & 1423 & 1439 & 1386 & 1563 & 1500 & 1445 & 1318 & 1277 & 1232 & 1177 & 1116 & 1043 & 1080 & 1058 & 994  & 1010 & 906  & 884  & 861  & 913  & 877  & 923  & 993  & 943  & 869  \\
        74 år   & 1583 & 1544 & 1505 & 1485 & 1397 & 1577 & 1723 & 1467 & 1399 & 1348 & 1287 & 1235 & 1182 & 1138 & 1121 & 1033 & 1088 & 1023 & 904  & 994  & 956  & 944  & 937  & 1032 & 1033 & 1064 \\
        75 år   & 1622 & 1706 & 1621 & 1459 & 1534 & 1453 & 1660 & 1690 & 1587 & 1439 & 1475 & 1340 & 1272 & 1265 & 1197 & 1087 & 1137 & 1081 & 1062 & 1020 & 987  & 1033 & 985  & 1026 & 1071 & 1085 \\
        76 år   & 1714 & 1752 & 1681 & 1569 & 1597 & 1548 & 1481 & 1694 & 1773 & 1705 & 1448 & 1453 & 1415 & 1302 & 1303 & 1224 & 1218 & 1189 & 1112 & 1051 & 1095 & 1014 & 1101 & 1086 & 1119 & 1116 \\
        77 år   & 1862 & 1858 & 1874 & 1782 & 1795 & 1677 & 1678 & 1596 & 1776 & 1796 & 1700 & 1582 & 1510 & 1527 & 1445 & 1319 & 1284 & 1258 & 1219 & 1205 & 1171 & 1174 & 1129 & 1146 & 1126 & 1182 \\
        78 år   & 1801 & 1888 & 1860 & 1822 & 1867 & 1714 & 1709 & 1593 & 1570 & 1870 & 1871 & 1687 & 1576 & 1600 & 1497 & 1373 & 1370 & 1334 & 1365 & 1307 & 1279 & 1325 & 1227 & 1196 & 1110 & 1197 \\
        79 år   & 1874 & 1975 & 1854 & 1914 & 1856 & 1680 & 1796 & 1706 & 1665 & 1595 & 1919 & 1906 & 1788 & 1681 & 1621 & 1504 & 1566 & 1435 & 1345 & 1335 & 1295 & 1349 & 1319 & 1246 & 1219 & 1196 \\
        80 år   & 1786 & 1906 & 1862 & 1882 & 1994 & 1860 & 1755 & 1763 & 1791 & 1652 & 1653 & 1879 & 1934 & 1846 & 1698 & 1630 & 1643 & 1580 & 1529 & 1468 & 1495 & 1452 & 1366 & 1400 & 1320 & 1288 \\
        81 år   & 1819 & 1983 & 1968 & 1872 & 1933 & 1837 & 1821 & 1860 & 1815 & 1775 & 1816 & 1624 & 1975 & 1944 & 1990 & 1745 & 1741 & 1698 & 1603 & 1647 & 1503 & 1484 & 1365 & 1538 & 1405 & 1350 \\
        82 år   & 1686 & 1810 & 1898 & 1940 & 1890 & 1775 & 1919 & 1821 & 1706 & 1761 & 1803 & 1763 & 1586 & 2045 & 1987 & 1777 & 1777 & 1698 & 1700 & 1639 & 1540 & 1560 & 1512 & 1544 & 1485 & 1486 \\
        83 år   & 1671 & 1699 & 1792 & 1841 & 1845 & 1753 & 1814 & 1873 & 1795 & 1789 & 1793 & 1757 & 1753 & 1658 & 2068 & 1922 & 1900 & 1766 & 1758 & 1724 & 1653 & 1660 & 1662 & 1587 & 1515 & 1566 \\
        84 år   & 1560 & 1632 & 1671 & 1681 & 1791 & 1728 & 1834 & 1804 & 1783 & 1845 & 1709 & 1729 & 1697 & 1715 & 1606 & 1959 & 2003 & 1917 & 1809 & 1761 & 1707 & 1648 & 1665 & 1661 & 1659 & 1540 \\
        85 år   & 1395 & 1449 & 1543 & 1601 & 1659 & 1594 & 1718 & 1745 & 1713 & 1794 & 1719 & 1703 & 1697 & 1719 & 1710 & 1606 & 1963 & 1942 & 1816 & 1775 & 1808 & 1715 & 1712 & 1672 & 1598 & 1647 \\
        86 år   & 1280 & 1424 & 1333 & 1404 & 1556 & 1460 & 1665 & 1635 & 1588 & 1641 & 1709 & 1695 & 1578 & 1605 & 1656 & 1574 & 1586 & 1902 & 1919 & 1828 & 1714 & 1748 & 1697 & 1741 & 1601 & 1605 \\
        87 år   & 1141 & 1171 & 1210 & 1266 & 1368 & 1260 & 1375 & 1494 & 1440 & 1486 & 1510 & 1579 & 1496 & 1623 & 1538 & 1491 & 1571 & 1489 & 1761 & 1885 & 1784 & 1696 & 1705 & 1717 & 1619 & 1597 \\
        88 år   & 961  & 1127 & 1083 & 1133 & 1205 & 1124 & 1240 & 1259 & 1347 & 1405 & 1409 & 1388 & 1426 & 1439 & 1424 & 1454 & 1449 & 1460 & 1411 & 1671 & 1761 & 1688 & 1559 & 1677 & 1544 & 1481 \\
        89 år   & 849  & 955  & 954  & 907  & 1049 & 972  & 1038 & 1114 & 1138 & 1158 & 1279 & 1203 & 1249 & 1344 & 1314 & 1255 & 1274 & 1338 & 1288 & 1377 & 1529 & 1586 & 1544 & 1556 & 1619 & 1535 \\
        90 år   & 683  & 741  & 815  & 879  & 864  & 759  & 888  & 904  & 985  & 1039 & 1054 & 1058 & 1129 & 1135 & 1097 & 1102 & 1182 & 1136 & 1201 & 1176 & 1201 & 1456 & 1459 & 1537 & 1329 & 1418 \\
        91 år   & 622  & 593  & 657  & 657  & 721  & 720  & 730  & 836  & 805  & 860  & 890  & 881  & 982  & 956  & 982  & 952  & 956  & 987  & 994  & 999  & 1052 & 1084 & 1305 & 1345 & 1351 & 1194 \\
        92 år   & 473  & 473  & 509  & 531  & 557  & 560  & 606  & 623  & 636  & 690  & 729  & 767  & 778  & 812  & 759  & 830  & 847  & 884  & 878  & 871  & 892  & 894  & 955  & 1121 & 1169 & 1086 \\
        93 år   & 350  & 357  & 406  & 387  & 461  & 430  & 474  & 493  & 505  & 529  & 547  & 573  & 615  & 700  & 635  & 670  & 735  & 684  & 740  & 736  & 735  & 747  & 758  & 800  & 981  & 946  \\
        94 år   & 270  & 285  & 313  & 299  & 326  & 307  & 349  & 353  & 380  & 368  & 424  & 437  & 434  & 454  & 478  & 452  & 558  & 524  & 604  & 585  & 600  & 577  & 618  & 619  & 666  & 727  \\
        95 år   & 184  & 199  & 234  & 253  & 235  & 234  & 268  & 257  & 275  & 284  & 291  & 330  & 336  & 363  & 360  & 377  & 404  & 358  & 419  & 431  & 464  & 414  & 449  & 519  & 480  & 512  \\
        96 år   & 126  & 147  & 169  & 153  & 199  & 173  & 159  & 198  & 198  & 197  & 224  & 241  & 245  & 262  & 269  & 236  & 262  & 310  & 308  & 297  & 316  & 334  & 317  & 348  & 356  & 351  \\
        97 år   & 107  & 120  & 104  & 118  & 125  & 136  & 124  & 132  & 156  & 127  & 144  & 140  & 159  & 166  & 166  & 176  & 206  & 191  & 202  & 221  & 221  & 243  & 252  & 254  & 250  & 268  \\
        98 år   & 68   & 76   & 64   & 72   & 68   & 78   & 73   & 77   & 72   & 88   & 89   & 110  & 111  & 96   & 106  & 126  & 113  & 135  & 153  & 137  & 169  & 151  & 162  & 168  & 171  & 164  \\
        99 år   & 46   & 33   & 51   & 50   & 58   & 45   & 46   & 47   & 60   & 57   & 60   & 63   & 71   & 76   & 59   & 62   & 55   & 81   & 82   & 95   & 104  & 108  & 102  & 132  & 116  & 105  \\
        100+ år & 63   & 56   & 72   & 63   & 69   & 64   & 72   & 88   & 78   & 74   & 83   & 80   & 100  & 95   & 94   & 97   & 93   & 108  & 128  & 130  & 146  & 165  & 128  & 166  & 156  & 190 
      \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

---

**The Output**

[image]

**The Techniques**

The techniques that have been used are,

1. Rotate the table by 90 degrees.
2. Reduce space before and after titles (chapter, section).
3. Reduce inter column separation.
4. Use smaller fonts.
5. Use `inputenc` so that the glyphs gets recognized.

Comment: @Mico Yes, of course. And that is the solution you have posted. We posted almost at the same time. The OP was bit unclear about what he was asking for.

Comment: @Mico I updated the answer. You deserve big thanks for playing the seeder role in this.

Comment: @Mico I will appreciate any other suggestions to improve my answer.

Comment: +1! Your updated code certainly achieves the goal originally set forth by the OP, viz., having chapter and section headers along with a landscape-oriented table all on one page. The only two things I'd change are (i) adding the instruction `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` so that the glyph `å` (lowercase a-angstrom) gets recognized and (ii) switching the column type of the 26 data columns from `l` to `r`, which may be achieved most parsimoniously via `\begin{tabular}{l*{26}{r}}`. Optional: load the `booktabs` package and replace the lone `\hline` with `\midrule`. :-)

Comment: @Mico Did all those. Let's make this perfect.